# react-aad-msal clearing localstorage. passing state around

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, frontend, react-aad-msal

So I've been hitting a wall over this last 2 days.
I haven't play around with ract/front end work for close to 2 years so please bear with me.

Scenario:
- load page
- throw stuff in localstorage (query string params)
- navigate to login authorization page (using react-aad-msal for this)
- get back to the main page
- try to retrieve data from localstorage and the keys I've added are missing. There are msal tokens etc present.

Enviroment:
- Chrome
- React plugin for debug

Unexpected twist: this happens at random. For the best part of yesterday it was working. and than the keys I've added started to go awol. Same thing this morning.

To my understanding - if I put something in localstorage, it stays there unless requested to be removed, programmatically or other way.

So what is going on here?

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example? If you are able to reproduce this bug without React, that would be even better.

Comment: If you run [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/artus/ok12f6yc/7/), close the page and then return, does the amount of items increase in the `alert` box?

Comment: @Titulum yes your sample works. I think it is that  react-aad-msal somewhat overriding the storage in particular paths but no clue when exactly.

Comment: And if you look at the local/sessionstorage in the Applications tab of Chrome's Developer Panel, you can't see when it is cleared ?

Comment: I can: it is gone when the authorization is calling back - I can see the localstorage having fields added, and then most of it is gone and limited to few msal records. That's why I link this behavior to said library. Reading through their doc now but nothing specific

Comment: What happens if you store your objects in a dedicated key for which you are sure no conflicts will arise? A key like `dont-touch-this-value`, is it still being cleared?

Comment: Inspecting the code of the [react-aad](https://github.com/syncweek-react-aad/react-aad) project, there are only 11 occurences of `localStorage`, with only 1 `localStorage.clear()` statement. This `clear()` statement is present in a test (`index.test.tsx`)

Answer (score 0):

Ok think I got it. It must be behavior of the msal - be it react-aad-msal or actual msal.js it is wrapping around. Anyway, solution proved to be to pass query string in state parameter on `AuthenticationParameters` when creating the provider omitting the local storage issue all together.

I just pass the query string from component:

```
<AzureAD
 provider={authProviderWithState(this.props.queryString)}
 reduxStore={this.props.reduxStore}
 forceLogin={false}>
```

Which is then glued on the top of defaults

```
export const authProviderWithState = (state) => {
    whichAuthParams.state = state;
    return new MsalAuthProvider(whichConfig, whichAuthParams, LoginType.Redirect);
};
```

State is simply appended to the callback url used by the authorization endpoint so it works as I need it.